# Symbol $\delta$ in the definition of geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I am reading [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086014000299), and the following definition of geodesic came up one line to the next without defining the symbol $\delta:$

> By definition, a geodesic line is a line of minimal length, for which $\delta\int \mathrm ds=0$  for fixed extremities of the line.

I have some idea of what a geodesic is in terms of, for instance, a line that when parameterized by arc length it shows only accelerations along the normal vector to the surface, etc.

But I don't know what $\delta$ stands for in the equation above, and I'm not sure I would understand the formula if I knew. So can I get an explanation?

Comment: You should edit the title. $\delta$ is the derivative symbol used in the calculus of variations. This sentence means that the curve is a stationary point of the length functional in the space of paths with fixed endpoints. This is a different notion from the extrinsic acceleration viewpoint.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much. I see where this is pointing to... A stability/stationary problem (Euler-Lagrange), and hence the zero in the RHS of the equation... It makes intuitive sense that this would be an alternative way to look at geodesics.